# How to switch column if condition

Tags: magento

I need to update a database with sku, qty, price and special price.

What i have is:

CSV File:

```
sku,qty,price
123,1,150
124,1,160
125,1,160
126,1,100
```

In table produdct content i have:

```
sku  qty  price  special_price
123   1   150     120
124   1   160     110
125   1   160     110
126   1   100     null
```

Good, in my case i need to compare

```
if special_price is >= than price,

if true update price 

else update special_price.
```

My php script is the next:

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

/***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/
function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

function _getTableName($tableName){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}

// Update Special Price
function _getPrice($attribute_code = 'price'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT attribute_id
                FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
            WHERE
                entity_type_id = ?
                AND attribute_code = ?";
    $entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
}

// Update Price
function _getSpecialPrice($attribute_code = 'special_price'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT attribute_id
                FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
            WHERE
                entity_type_id = ?
                AND attribute_code = ?";
    $entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
}
// Get Entity TypeID
function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
}
// Get ID from SKU
function _getIdFromSku($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));

}
// Check if SKU exist in DB
function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    $count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

// Switch price method if special_price is = or > price.
function _checkPrice($sku) {
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . " WHERE special_price >=" . $data[2];
    $count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array(_getIdFromSku($sku)));
    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function _updatePrice($data){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $qty       = $data[1];
    $price       = $data[2];
    $productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId    = _getPrice();

    $sql = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " cped
                SET  cped.value = ?
            WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?
            AND cped.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql, array($qty, $price, $attributeId, $productId));
}

function _updateSpecialPrice($data){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $qty       = $data[1];
    $price       = $data[2];
    $productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId    = _getSpecialPrice();

    $sql = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " cped
                SET  cped.value = ?
            WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?
            AND cped.entity_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql, array($qty, $price, $attributeId, $productId));
}
/***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/

$csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
$data               = $csv->getData('data.csv'); //path to csv
array_shift($data);

$message = '';
$count   = 1;
foreach($data as $_data){
    if(_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0]) and _checkPrice == TRUE){
        try{
            _updatePrice($_data);
            $message .= $count . '  Success:: Updated:  ' . $_data[1] . 'Pret:  ' . $_data[2] . '   Sku:    ' . $_data[0] . '<br />';

        }catch(Exception $e){
            $message .=  $count .'> Error:: ' . $_data[1] . '   AND ' . $_data[2] . '   of Sku  ' . $_data[0] . '   => '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
        }
    }elseif(_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0]) and _checkPrice == FALSE){
        try{
            _updateSpecialPrice($_data);
            $message .= $count . '  Updated:    ' . $_data[1] . 'Pret:  ' . $_data[2] . '   Sku:    ' . $_data[0] . '<br />';

        }catch(Exception $e){
            $message .=  $count .'> Error:: ' . $_data[1] . '   AND ' . $_data[2] . '   of Sku  ' . $_data[0] . '   => '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
        }else{
        $message .=  $count .'  Error:: Product with sku    ' . $_data[0] . '   doesnt exist<br />';
    }
    }
    $count++;
}
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use magento's import function? if you need to compare old prices / special prices vs new ones, just pull a list of your products and make a small script to create an updated import csv.

Comment: Yes i know, but the problem if that i receive the data bulk, i can split it to stock and price, but still need to compare price and update the correct price.

Comment: which is very basic, read your export and import list into arrays, write some simple code to compare what you need to compare and update the import array accordingly, then print it to csv. Read about php functions on http://www.php.net/manual/en/